# Div hover not working?

Tags: html, css, hover

I have a div that refuses to change background colors when I hover over it. It stays the same. Here's the code.

HTML:

```
<div id="login"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#login {
    position: fixed;
    float: left;
    background-color: none;
    margin-left: 1.5%;
    top: 1em;
    height: 1.25em;
    width: 7em;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: .3em;
    opacity: .5;
    padding-top: 1em;
    border: .18em solid gray;
}

#login:hover {
    background-color: gray;
}
```

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: Works for me [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/353x4/). Are you sure you've linked the CSS properly to your HTML file?

Comment: It works for me too, seems that some of your other css has been inherited on the div. Use your browser developer tools to inspect it to see what's going on.

Comment: I have a similar issue, the problem is a space between colon and `hover` keyword

Comment: This is some reason, check below:
1. Type error: There is a space before the selector and `:hover`;
2. Override: Some higher priority style override it;

Comment: If it helps anyone i was using a background-image in the inactive state then in the active state i.e onhover i was using background-color which was not working. Well it was a silly mistake.

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem.  What I suggest is making sure there are no invisible objects over the div. This tells the program that your cursor is hovering the invisible object rather than the div with the hover element.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22767946)

Comment: I believe it could fix the problem that has been failed to be completely answered already.

Answer (score 3):

Works fine for me - http://jsfiddle.net/Q8A6d/

Which browser are you using? You cannot apply a

```
:hover
```

pseudo class to any elements other than `<a>` in older versions of IE (6 and below).

Answer (score 2):

Your code appears to work properly [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/353x4/), so a few things could be wrong:

1. You might have linked your stylesheet to your HTML file improperly.
2. Some other CSS in the context of your project may be overriding the piece that you've given here.
3. You might be running into browser compatibility issues with the `:hover` selector or something else in your code that is breaking the styling.

Comment: Another thing that can cause mouse events to fail is the element has or is within an element that has a minus z-index value